# How do I handle widthChange event on YUI panels?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, yui

I have a resizable panel on my system that has a a title.
If the user changes the size of the panel, I need to check the size of the title and add "..." to it if the site of the title is bigger than the size of the panel.

The code to check the size of the string, etc, I already have it, but the thing is, how to subscribe or listen to the correct event.

Reading the docs for YUI I found the event `widthChange` but can't find a way to correctly subscribe to it.

Any ideas/ help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is not a direct solution for my problem but I came across this solution, using CSS.
The application was displaying the panel title using a SPAN, so What I had to do was simply add the following to the SPAN class:

```
display:block; 
white-space:nowrap; 
overflow:hidden; 
margin-right:45px;  // the margin in this case was just to avoid clash with the small close button on the right side
text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

This is quite simple and no need for JS code. Hope it help someone with the same problem.